# Ban limit on discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Is it possible to make a ban limit? Discord js
And for the one who gives more than 5 ban to receive ban?

```js
bot.on('guildBanAdd', (guild, user) => {
```

Is this event ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you suggested won't exactly work, as the `user` parameter gives the `User` who was *banned*, not the user who *banned them*. To get the user who executed the banning, we'll have to use audit logs. I suggest you read [Discord.js Guide - Who Banned a User](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/audit-logs.html#who-banned-a-user) to read more about how the audit logs work, as I won't be going into much detail.

To track values, the best thing to use would be a database; this way they won't reset when you restart your bot. However, if you can't do that, you can use a [`Map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Or even better, a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/general/welcome):

```js
const { Collection } = require("discord.js");
const banlogs = new Collection();

bot.on("guildBanAdd", (guild, user) => {
  const banLog = fetchedLogs.entries.first(); // get the ban log
  if (!banLog) return; // if the fetch was unsuccesful, return
  const { executor, target } = banLog; // get user who was banned and user who banned them
  if (target.id !== user.id || !executor) return; // if the target doesn't match the user from the event or no executor, return

  if (!banlogs.has(executor.id))
    // if our collection doesn't have the executor
    banlogs.set(executor.id, new Collection([[guild.id, 1]]);
  // add the executor to the collection, it's value being another collection, and add the guild to that with a value of 1 [ban]
  else if (!banlogs.get(executor.id).has(guild.id))
    // if it has the executor but not the guild
    banlogs.get(executor.id).set(guild.id, 1);
  // add it with a value of 1 [ban]
  // if the collection has the executor AND the guild
  else banlogs.get(executor.id).get(guild.id)++; // increment the ban count by one
  if (banlogs.get(executor.id).get(guild.id) > 5)
    // check the ban count
    guild.member(executor).ban({ reason: "Over 5 Bans" }); // ban the user
});
```